# Initializing a custom field that is defined but empty by default?

Tags: c#, jira, jira-rest-api

so in our Jira, we have a custom field "X" that is empty by default. To my surprise, it is not returned at all when listing through CustomFields of a newly created issue, and therefore I cannot simply use:

```
issue.CustomFields["X"].Values == ...
```

because such a field would not be found.

It only becomes available in the RestAPI when a user enters some data via Jira UI. However, I would need to be able programmatically to initialize this field in certain cases but I cannot figure out how.

EDIT:
I test if the field is there:

```
if (x.CustomFields.Where(CustomField => CustomField.Name=="X").Count()==0)
{
   //NOT FOUND - I need to initialize it (cannot just set its value for the reasons stated above}
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: what lang is this?
```issue.CustomFields["X"].Values == //value```

Comment: @developer C# but the question should be agnostic of that.

Comment: not really if it was client side JS you could wrap in a simple "if" else.
what type is ```issue.CustomFields```

Comment: if ```Dictionary<TKey,TValue>```
then test for key ```Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ContainsKey(TKey) Method``` 
ref: ```https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=net-5.0```

Comment: well the thing is - the field is not listed in the CustomFields (type CustomFieldValue). Only after it has been initialized via UI

Comment: Which client are you using?

Comment: @Genusatplay namespaces Atlassian.Jira and RestSharp

Comment: You try this? https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-fields/#api-rest-api-3-field-post

Comment: @Genusatplay That is something else - that is about creating the custom field as an administrator, truly adding a new one to the system. In my case, the custom field is defined in the system. It is just empty and for reason, REST API customFields list does not contain it until its value is set.

Comment: Guessing `CustomFields` is of type `CustomFieldValueCollection`(https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/master/Atlassian.Jira/CustomFieldValueCollection.cs) you should be able to add values with `Add(fieldName, value)`?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen  ...you are right! I have overlooked that one..thanks a million! EDIT: It is a step forward, but the error now says "It cannot be set..."

Comment: Can you post the full error message? Looks like the SDK queries available fields when you tried to set a field by name (to get the fieldId) but there should be a different error if field was not found.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen It is the following: customfield cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.  I have found a discussion where a guy is told that he is simply trying to add field to a screen where this is not allowed. I do not get it - I use the REST call, and for the very same issue I can edit the value in Jira itself. Just not using the REST. (https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/customfield-cannot-be-set/6099)

Comment: I remember I had some fun with jira and fields not visible on screens but it's too long ago and I don't remember the details. I found this article tha might help https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/#getting-metadata-for-creating-issues-examples - at least, we now "know" it's not the client but looks like a jira configuration issue.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Thanks, would you know how to obtain this metadata using the client? I cannot seem to fidn any method fot that

Comment: I'd use the curl examples and try to understand what jira defines as available at that point.